# Java Method Not Running

Tags: java

I have a quick question.

I have this method here which says that the variable "worker" is not being used.  What kind of syntax would I write below it in order to run it?  I have printed a system.out line and it is not running.

```
        SQLWorker worker = new SQLWorker(SQLEngine.UPDATE_HIGH_SCORES) {
        @Override
        public ResultSet executeSQL(Connection c, PreparedStatement st)
                throws SQLException {
            System.out.println("part 2");
            return null;
        }
    };
```

As well as the method not running, Eclipse also says "worker" isn't being used.

Comment: Who is calling the method ?

Comment: On a completely unrelated note, *cough* hibernate *cough*. It makes this kind of thing sooooo much sweeter =)

Comment: This is not a method. This is a variable declaration and initializaion. And the variable is initialized wih a new instance of an anonymous class which extends SQLWorker and overrides one of its methods. If you don't use the variable worker later in the code, then this doesn't do anything (other than the potential side-effects of the SQLWorker constructor)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, you are only defining the `worker`. In order to run something do : e.g. `worker.executeSQL(...)`

Answer (score 0):

Write `worker.` below your snippet, and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SPACE</kbd>. You should see API suggestions, and you will find your "run" method there (can be something like `run()`, `execute()`, `doQuery()` etc. - read the javadoc).

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to archive? I ask this because i assume you dont want to use that google classes :)

**The warning:**

Thats because you crate a object worker but seem to never use it afterwards. Call worker.executeSQL (the method you overriden) or any other method you gained there.

**The Problem:**

I dont use those google classes so i dont know what the SQLWorker is used for, your source however seems to be correct... but i doubt its useful for what you try to archive ;)